# how to add category products (only 4 products) in homepage rwd theme?

Tags: category-products

I want to display each category (only 4 products) on the homepage. I m new in Magento.

### Biscuits/Cookies

[View all products](http://urkart.com/index.php/ready-foods/biscuits-cookies.html)

```
{{block type=”catalog/product_list” name=”home.catalog.product.list” alias=”products_homepage” category_id=”4″ template=”catalog/product/custom_list.phtml”}}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add code  `limit=4` and need change name and repeat the code for each category

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.products_homepage_4" alias="products_homepage_4" category_id="4" template="catalog/product/custom_list.phtml" limit="4"}}
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.products_homepage_5" alias="products_homepage_5" category_id="6" template="catalog/product/custom_list.phtml" limit="4"}}
```

Comment: only 1 category show & only 1 product show in homepage. i want display 4 products of each category on homepage.

Comment: no its not worked... only 1 category & 1 produt show in homepge. i want to display 4 products of each category on homepage.. help me..

Comment: which magento version .is used?

Comment: 1.9.0.1 rwd theme

Comment: magento 1.9.0.1 is used.

Comment: I will give solutions today

Comment: sir i m waiting..

Comment: Amit sir it is not working in magento 1.9.1.0 can you please update the code?

Comment: i will check and let you know